# Python merge dataframes warning

Tags: python, pandas, merge, warnings

I am getting this warning when merging 2 dataframes, 1 of which is created from a pivot:

```
UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left,2 on the right) warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

I don't see what the issue is as both dataframes are created from the same original data (I am a complete novice however). Abridged code below:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    gdp_totals = gdp_data.pivot_table(values="Value", index="TIME", aggfunc=[np.sum, np.mean, np.median])
    print(gdp_totals.info())

    gdp_ire = gdp_data[gdp_data['LOCATION'] == "IRL"].copy()
    gdp_ire.set_index('TIME', inplace=True)
    gdp_ire['Annual%'] = np.nan       # insert blank column
    for i in gdp_ire.index:
        if i == 1970:
            gdp_ire.loc[i, 'Annual%'] = 0
        else:
            gdp_ire.loc[i, 'Annual%'] = (gdp_ire.loc[i, 'Value']-gdp_ire.loc[i-1, 'Value'])/gdp_ire.loc[i-1, 'Value']*100

    gdp_all = gdp_ire.merge(gdp_totals, on='TIME', suffixes=['_IRE', '_TOTALS'], how='left')
```

Snip of the pivot:

[image: pivot snip]

snip of gdp_ire:

[image: ire snip]

Shape of the dataframes:

```
    print(gdp_totals.shape)
    print(gdp_ire.shape)
```

[image: shapes]

Snip of the original data that I'm subsetting:

[image: original data]

Comment: are your columns multi-level columns?

Comment: I'm a complete novice, so basically I don't know, though I don't think so. I'm subsetting from a much larger data set, I've added a snip of it above. For gdp_ire I've subset by location, is this maybe the issue? Though I though by using .copy() I would avoid issues.